# React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dropzone

I am implementing an upload file dropzone within my react web application using react-dropzone, which I intend to send a post request to my .NET Core Web API to parse the file and save it to a DB. I am using this [tutorial](https://medium.com/technoetics/handling-file-upload-in-reactjs-b9b95068f6b) as a guide whilst making my own adjustments to suit my project spec, and I keep getting the below error which I am unsure how to fix:

> Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Upload`.

This error stops the application from rendering the component. 
I have researched the error and found the following answers however I believe they are unrelated to my issues.

- https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2220
- https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/warning-react-createelement/

Please see my Upload component below:

```
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/FontIcon';
import { blue500 } from 'material-ui/styles/colors';
import { PageHeader, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';

const request = require('superagent');

const apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api/';

const style = {
  margin: 15,
};

const title = 'Upload';

class Upload extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      filesPreview: [],
      filesToBeSent: [],
      printcount: 10,
    };
    context.setTitle(title);
  }

  onDrop(acceptedFiles) {
    console.log('Accepted files: ', acceptedFiles[0].name);
    const filesToBeSent = this.state.filesToBeSent;
    if (filesToBeSent.length < this.state.printcount) {
      filesToBeSent.push(acceptedFiles);
      const filesPreview = [];
      Object.keys(filesToBeSent).forEach((key, i) => {
        filesPreview.push(<div>
          {filesToBeSent[i][0].name}
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <a href=""><FontIcon
              className="material-icons customstyle"
              color={blue500}
              styles={{ top: 10 }}
            >clear</FontIcon></a>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
          );
      });
      this.setState({ filesToBeSent, filesPreview });
    } else {
      alert('You have reached the limit of printing files at a time');
    }
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    console.log('handleClick: ', event);
    const self = this;
    console.log('self: ', self);
    if (this.state.filesToBeSent.length > 0) {
      const filesArray = this.state.filesToBeSent;
      const req = request.post(`${apiBaseUrl}fileupload`);
      Object.keys(filesArray).forEach((key, i) => {
        console.log('files', filesArray[i][0]);
        req.attach(filesArray[i][0].name, filesArray[i][0]);
        req.end((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('error ocurred');
          }
          console.log('res', res);
          alert('File printing completed');
        });
      });
    } else {
      alert('Please upload some files first');
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12">
            <PageHeader>Upload Data</PageHeader>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-8 col-sm-4">
            <Panel
              header={<span>
                <i className="fa fa-location-arrow fa-fw" /> Drag
                      and drop your file here, or use the file browser:
                    </span>}
            >
              <div className="App col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                <Dropzone onDrop={(files) => this.onDrop(files)}>
                  <div>Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.</div>
                </Dropzone>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-4 col-sm-2">
                 Files to be printed are:
                  {this.state.filesPreview}
              </div>
              <MuiThemeProvider>
                <RaisedButton
                  label="Print Files" style={style}
                  onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}
                />
              </MuiThemeProvider>
            </Panel>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Upload.contextTypes = { setTitle: PropTypes.func.isRequired };
export default Upload;
```

Thanking you in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import for `RaisedButton` is wrong. It should be

```
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
```

The import for PageHeader is also wrong. It should be

```
import { PageHeader, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

With your current imports it doesn't find `RaisedButton` and `PageHeader`.

---

To find the problems I've temporarily added log statements to the render method:

```
render() {
  console.log("Panel", panel);
  console.log("MuiThemeProvider", MuiThemeProvider);
  //... for all components
  return (
    //...
  );
}
```

---

As to the question: "when do I `import React from 'react';`" versus "when do I `import { Component } from 'react';`:

This depends on the module that your are trying to import and how it exports the things it exports. See [export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) for the details.

A module can have one (and only one) "default export" (but it does not need do provide a default exprort!) and an arbitrary number of "named exports".

Whatever it is that the module exports with `export default ...;`, you can import that with `import MyName from 'someModule';`. Basically you are free to choose `MyName` to your liking, however it might confuse readers of your code if your choosen name doesn't match their expectations. And for example the JSX transpiler requires that you do the import as `import React from 'react';`.

For all the other things that a module exports (by name), you have to write an import statement like `import { Component } from 'react';` - the module exports `Component` under that name, and if you want to import `Component` you have to name it explicitly.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have fixed this import, thanks for pointing that out. However, I am still getting the above error in console and component is still not rendering. Thanks

Comment: @devdc I found the second problem and updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for your persistence and help! I have fixed this. Would you mind explaining to me when to use  `import { PageHeader, Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';` and when to use `import Dropzone from 'react-dropzone';` for example when importing in React? I am a little unsure of when I should be directly importing and when I should be using `{ }` within my imports. Many thanks once again.

Comment: @devdc I've added some information about the JavaScript import/export mechanism